# Decoding filename issue

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, codec

To simplify my question, I have created a working demonstration, which should work according to the python unicode documentation on handling filenames.  The output is as follows:

```
$ ./test_unicode.py /tmp/gsynctest/Greg.*
p = '/tmp/gsynctest/Greg. Descripci\xf3n v\xeddeos'
up = u'/tmp/gsynctest/Greg. Descripci\xf3n v\xeddeos'
up.utf8 = /tmp/gsynctest/Greg. Descripción vídeos
Command line file exists = True
Unicode file exists = False
UTF-8 file exists = False
```

As you can see, in order of appearance, `p` is the filename provided through argv and the glob.  It has a "latin-1" encoding despite my terminal having LANG="en_GB.UTF-8".  If I decode it with strict unicode errors set, I get the string shown by `up`.  If I then encode it in utf8, I get something that represents the real filename.

However, according to the unicode documentation, sys.getfilesystemencoding() should be used to encode a unicode filename for accessing it.  This doesn't work though.  The three `exists` checks show which one works and it seems to be the latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) encoding.

I have no idea why what I am seeing does not reflect the documentation.

Here is the test program code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os

paths = sys.argv[1:]

fsenc = sys.getfilesystemencoding()

for p in paths:
    print "p = %s" % repr(p)

    if not isinstance(p, unicode):
        up = unicode(p, encoding = "latin-1", errors = "strict")

    print "up = %s" % repr(up)
    print "up.utf8 = %s" % up.encode("utf8")

    print "Command line file exists = %s" % os.path.exists(p)
    print "Unicode file exists = %s" % os.path.exists(up)
    print "%s file exists = %s" % (fsenc, os.path.exists(up.encode(fsenc)))
```

. . .

Original Question:

If I attempt to decode the following filename representation in its raw form, I get an 'invalid continuation byte' error: `Greg. Descripci\xf3n v\xeddeos\n`

```
for p in paths:
    p = p.decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

This is a genuine file name submitted by a user that has filed this bug.  My understanding of unicode / UTF-8 encoding isn't great, but from what I gather, it is not legal UTF-8 because it expects some sort of terminator.  I don't really care how the filename looks when printed, it just needs to be accessible on disk.  What is the conventional way to handle files like this?  Most of my issues stem from trying to print the file:

```
debug(u"Filename: %s" % unicode(path))
```

Update: Would a try, try harder, try harder still approach do any good?

```
for e in (sys.getfilesystemencoding(), "UTF-8", "Latin-1"):
    try:
        p_dec = p.decode("Latin-1")
        p = p_dec.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        pass
```

Obviously not so optimal for encodings where the file system encoding is the same, since it will decode and encode in the same encoding.  But at least I can guarantee that there will be no exceptions decoding the file name with subsequent calls.  The only issue I see, is that there is potential for the incorrect encoding to decode the file name without error and thus produce an encoded file name that is just completely wrong.

Either way, do I need to track two file names?  The original file name that is accessible on disk and the printable file name? Or will the file system encoded file name be both printable and accessible?

Update 2:  The answer to my question is "no".  I implemented a codec of my own to cycle encoding types and re-encode in the file system encoding.  The representation is now printable: `Greg. Descripción vídeos` but the file is no longer accessible.  So I assume the easiest way to retain file system access and printability is to wrap the filename in a class with an implementation for both printing and IO; unless anybody has any other suggestions that is?

Comment: UTF-8 doesn't "expect some sort of terminator". But `\xf3` after `i` is not part of any valid UTF-8 string. This is almost certainly Latin-1 or something related, like cp1252.

Comment: Also, it's not clear from your description which line is getting this string and raising this exception. Is it the `p.decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())`, or the `unicode(path)`?

Comment: What OS? On Windows, use unicode strings for filenames to avoid the code-page-limited byte filename handling of C stdio functions.

Comment: Linux.  It seems that `p` is printable after all.  Something was happening to `p` in another function that was transforming it by wrapping it in `unicode()`.  That was an easy fix.  Then another exception arose as a result of a regex constructed from the file path not being printable in a debug statement.  I fixed this by wrapping in a `repr()` statement.  I get unprintable characters, but I am not too bothered by these, I just would rather it didn't throw exceptions.

Comment: I don't get what you think you're seeing that doesn't reflect the documentation. Python is detecting that your filesystem is UTF-8 (as you can see by printing out `sys.getfilesystemencoding()`). When you try `os.stat(up)`, it's being encoded to UTF-8, just as the docs say, so you get the exact same result as when you encode explicitly, just as you should. The problem here is apparently that your filesystem is not UTF-8, even though your locale implies that it should be.

Comment: Meanwhile, on linux, filesystems effectively ignore anything about filenames except for ASCII NUL and '/' bytes. Some apps, like anything built with Qt, will assume that all filenames are encoded in UTF-8; others, like anything built with Glib/Gtk+, will assume they're encoded in your locale; but there's nothing stopping you from mixing and matching, and having filenames that half your apps can't display properly.

Comment: Finally, if decoding from Latin-1 and then encoding to UTF-8 to print is producing readable output, that means your terminal is UTF-8, _not_ Latin-1. That would imply that just doing `ls /tmp/gsynctest/Greg*` should show mojibake, because the Latin-1-named filenames you have there are nonsense as UTF-8. However, some UTF-8 decoders are more lenient than Python's, and try to treat any invalid byte as if it were Latin-1, so your test case might actually look valid anyway, which makes this much harder to debug.

Comment: Anyway, if you just want things to work, even on a screwed-up system where there are both Latin-1 filenames and UTF-8 filenames, the only thing you can really do is _not_ interpret them; leave them as un-decoded `str` all the way through. As long as all of the charsets have the same code point for '/' and have no embedded NUL bytes, that should work.

Comment: I up-voted your comment.  I gave up on this late last night but came to the same realization while half asleep, still thinking about it.  I haven't checked yet, but in my own stupidity, I do believe that I have managed to create a filename that has latin-1 encodings on a UTF-8 filesystem.  So that begs the question of expectation.  If I was to copy this file elsewhere, should I transcode the filename into the correct encoding or literally restore it in its original locale?  I'm thinking transcode.

Comment: Following on from your last comment, I had wanted to do exactly that, but the dreaded 'ordinal not in range' error when trying to concatenate or modify the string, like: `os.path.join("/some/path/", orig_path)`.  Since the filename encoding is completely messed up, I am thinking that I will just ignore this issue and just handle legitimate encodings.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: It seems the only thing that produces an error is if I try to implicitly encode using `str()`.  Concatenation actually seems to work.  That said, I only use `str()` on instances of classes I created that implement a `__str__` method that returns the path.  These are where it "excepts".  Is there any other way I can retain this functionality, other than explicitly implementing a `getPath` method?  For example:  `normpath = os.path.normalize(myobj.getPath(), otherpath)` as opposed to `normpath = os.path.normalize(str(myobj), otherpath)`

Answer (score 1):

First, it's almost always a bad idea to just write `unicode(path)`. If you need to convert a string to Unicode, you need to know what charset it's in.

Assuming `p` represents a path from the filesystem (e.g., you got it from `os.listdir`), then you want to decode it with the filesystem's encoding, not just whatever Python thinks is a nice default.* So, the right thing to do is what you already did above:

```
p = p.decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

If `path` represents something else (e.g., you got it from user input), that's a different story.

Or, if `path` is one of those `p` values you already calculated above, then it's *already* `unicode`, so trying to decode it again is going to re-encode it to your default encoding and then re-decode it, which is a silly thing to do.

But without knowing where the string came from, you (and we) can't know what charset it's in, and therefore you can't know how to decode it.

---

* On some systems, you'll get lucky. For example, with Python 3.x on a Mac, the default encoding and the filesystem encoding will both always be UTF-8. But with Python 2.x on an older linux box, the default encoding may be UTF-8 while the filesystem is Latin-1… which seems to be exactly what you're getting here.

Comment: It is both a path on the file system and provided as an argument.  In order to repro the issue, I created the file as the user has it.  I then used a glob on the command line to provide it as an argument: `myprog /path/to/Greg*`.  Two different errors occur with the code I provided above.  unicode(path) produces the infamous 'ordinal not in range' exception.  I understand that you can't just expect unicode() to just figure it out, as nice as that would be.  The unicode() call is just an example of existing code that I modified to `debug("File: %s" % repr(path))`.  So that leaves decode().

Comment: @Craig: "It is a path on the file system" isn't what matter, it's whether you _got_ it from the filesystem, or from user input (or somewhere else, like a JSON RPC call from another machine). Something that comes from, say, `sys.argv[1]` or `raw_input` is going to be in the user's terminal's encoding, which will be `sys.stdin.encoding` if Python was able to figure it out, but not `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` (unless you get lucky as their filesystem and terminal happen to use the same encoding—guaranteed on Mac, but not most other POSIX systems).

Comment: Okay, the initial paths provided on input are in terminal encoding.  However, these paths are walked by os.walk() to recursively process them.  So some paths with be file system encoded, others will be terminal.  It is actually easy to distinguish which are which.  The problem is, that when I encode the filename in the file system encoding after having decoded it, it is no longer accessible.  If I leave the filename in its native form, it can be accessed.  But in native form it cannot be joined with anything else using os.path.join.  The only reasonable solution left is a wrapper.

Comment: What do you mean by "no longer accessible"? Meanwhile, as a general rule, decode things as soon as possible, keep them in Unicode as long as possible, encode back as late as possible. You can use `os.path` on `unicode` strings as long as you do so consistently (don't try to `join` a `str` and ` unicode`). Anyway, it would help if you gave us a complete example—runnable code with a fully-described test case—instead of a trickle of information a little bit at a time.

Comment: Accessible:  `for p in path:` `p` is accessible.  `p.decode("latin-1").encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())` not accessible, i.e. File not found.

Comment: Are you sure `p` is Latin-1 in that case? Are you sure your filesystem is UTF-8 (or whatever `sys.getfilesystemencoding` returns)? Again, please give us a complete example, with all the information, instead of little fragments a bit at a time.

Comment: Okay.  According to the python documentation, file system operations should support unicode, since it will use the file system encoding or LANG environment variable to encode internally, which ever is set, or ascii by default.  I know the terminal is providing the ISO-8859-1 encoding (latin-1) since if I do a latin-1 decode followed by a utf8 encoding and print it, I can read the output (proper characters are output).  However, trying to access the file using the unicode filename fails: `os.stat(unicode_filename)`

Answer (score 0):

The string `Greg. Descripci\xf3n v\xeddeos\n` is encoded in latin-1 or some other non-Unicode and non-UTF-8 encoding, so you'll want to do this:

```
"Greg. Descripci\xf3n v\xeddeos\n".decode('latin-1').encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

this yields:

```
'Greg. Descripci\xc3\xb3n v\xc3\xaddeos\n'
```

The problem is that your own file system encoding may not match the encoding used to submit a file or filename via the web.  You may need to check the incoming encoding to see what the actual encoding is.  It may or may not be latin-1:  I just used latin-1 because it's the most universal 8 bit encoding used.

(Depending on what you're doing, you may not actually need to re-encode it.)